# Can't get span text using csspath

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

Im querying a span element (without class, id, or anything) using csspath in selenium c# but the text attribute is empty.

what's happening and how can I get the text within the span?

So the DOM structure is:

```
/div/div/ul/li/a/span
```

Query is:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".contactActions .iconActions .icon .privacy span"));
```

Comment: well I have no idea what your html is so how would I know if your selector, which seems to go off mostly classes, is accurate

Comment: You have 6 nested elements in your DOM structure and 8 nested elements in your CSS selector, there is obviously something wrong, you'd better show html.

Comment: There I uploaded the html.. thanks!

Comment: You should see if you can grab the HTML as text to post here instead of uploading a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='otherOuterDiv']//span"));
```

I usually use relative XPaths, because I find it easier to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

string text = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".contactActions .iconActions .icon .privacy span")).GetAttribute("textContent"));